# How to return a CompletableFuture from the thenApply of another CompletableFuture in Java?

Tags: java, promise, future, chaining, completable-future

I am new to the concept of `CompletableFuture` in Java, so I don't know a whole lot about it and its functions other than `thenApply`

I have a requirement where I have to test some condition in the `thenApply` block of a `CompletableFuture` **A**. If the condition is satisfied, return null, else return another `CompletableFuture` **B** so that in the next `thenApply`, the result will be that of **B**.

Basically I am trying to do something like the following:

```
CompletableFuture<String> A = ......
CompletableFuture<Boolean> B = ......

A.thenApply((res) -> {
  if (res.equals("hey")) {
   return null;
  } else {
   return B;
  }
})
.thenApply((bResult) -> { // At this point, I want it to act as if I was calling B.thenApply

   //some function;
})
```

Is this possible? Can I return a `CompletableFuture` from another `CompletableFuture` so that the next `thenApply` on the chain will actually be a `thenApply` of the returned `CompletableFuture`?

Also, if I want to cancel the next `thenApply`s on some condition. How do I do that?

Comment: Can you use Guava's ListenableFuture? If so you want a ListenableFuture, and your "thenApply" is Guava's Futures.transformAsync

Comment: Well you can `return B.join ()` which would have that effect. But you'd also continue if you return `null` (ie "hey" case).

Comment: Looks like you want `thenCompose`. But to use it, you have to rethink you habit of returning `null`…

Comment: >Can I return a CompletableFuture from another CompletableFuture ..? : Yes, you can declare it like `CompletableFuture<CompletableFuture<?>>` ...and "all generic layers" in between `CompletableFuture<?>`, `CompletableFuture<CompletableFuture<String>>` (resp. `...<Boolean>>`) ...in case of `<?>` (equiv. to  `<java.lang.Object>`), you could do an instance check (`instanceof`or equiv.), cast and treat it accordingly (as `String/Boolean/CompletableFuture`)

Comment: @Holger thenComopose is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.